# Is it possible to take screenshots at arbitrary moment and also keep the takeonfail value as true in testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

At present, I am not able to figure out the screenshot functionality of TestCafe.

I want to take screenshots at arbitrary moments in my test case but I also want to keep the `takeOnFails` option as true in the TestCafe configuration file. But whenever I do so the test case only takes screenshots when the test fails. For successful runs, I cannot find any screenshot. If I remove the `takeOnFails` option from the configuration file then I get screenshots for passed test cases.

This is how the screenshot section looks in the TestCafe configuration file:

```
"screenshots": {
    "path": "./screenshots",
    "takeOnFails": true,
    "pathPattern": "${DATE}_${TIME}/test-${TEST_INDEX}/${USERAGENT}/${FILE_INDEX}.png",
    "fullPage": true
}
```

And I using await `t.takeScreenshot()` in the test case to take screenshots at arbitrary places.

Could some please help and suggest how I can take screenshots for both passed and failed test cases

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you refer to the [Take Screenshots at Arbitrary Moments During Test Run](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/screenshots-and-videos.html#take-screenshots-at-arbitrary-moments-during-test-run) documentation topic where this inquiry is described.